# What is the type theory judgement symbol?

Tags: logic, terminology, type-theory

In type theory judgements are often presented with the following syntax:

[image]

My question is what is that symbol in the middle called? All the papers I've found seem to use an image rather than a unicode character so I can't look it up. I've also not found any type-theory reference which says what that symbol is (they explain what it means however).

So what character is that symbol and what is its proper name?

Comment: Note that $\models$ `\models` is also often used in logics.

Comment: @Raphael: $\models$ is used for semantic relationships. $\vdash$ is used for syntactic relationships, such as in proof systems.

Comment: @DaveClarke: Of course, I did not want to suggest otherwise. My intention was to leave the trail to $\models$ here, too, as you might also want to type that one if you do logics. (I know we did some weird foo before knowing `\models`...)

Comment: It's a good trail to follow.

Comment: Yes, that symbol appears often as well. These comments save me another question about it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a "turnstile". See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_%28symbol%29).

Answer (score 4):

#### Detexify

Draw the character on [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to see what (La)TeX command generates it.

Oddly, I can't get Detexify to recognize this character. `\vdash` comes up eventually, but with a very bad score no matter how well I try to draw it.

#### Shapecatcher

Draw the character on [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) to see what it is in Unicode. It's U+22A2 RIGHT TACK (⊢).

The usual name in math is [turnstile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_%28symbol%29). In this context, it's sometimes called the inference symbol or the deduction symbol. The $\Gamma$ on the left is a *context* or *environment*.

Comment: Shapecatcher is nice. So many symbols.  I also trained Detexify until it now comes up near the top.

Comment: I couldn't help but try Detexify. I couldn't get it to recognise $\vdash$ either. Grrr.

Comment: Too many badly drawn crosses trained.